# FileUriEXposedException in Sharing screenshot of a layout

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, uri

Hey i am trying to share the screen shot of a layout. it works very well in all very version which are less than Oreo, but when i am trying to share on Oreo it is giving FileUriExposedException. Please If anyone knows about this issue please solve it as soon as possible.

Here is my code

```
 public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     imagepath1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagepath1);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }


}
private void shareIt() {
    try{
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagepath1);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    String share_text = "*Create, Share, Download* Valentine Frames and spread love on this \nValentine\uD83D\uDE18\uD83D\uDE18 for free...." +
            "\n*Download Now:-* https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=technoapps4.valentineframes2019";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_text);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));}
    catch ( Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK sharing files by sharing their paths is not allowed anymore since oreo. I got this issue some time ago.

My solution was to share the file content with a content-provider.